# Use wildcard in tar with -T option

Tags: tar, wildcard

I have a backup script that has this syntax "tar -czvf backup.tar.gz -T filelist"
In this filelist, I'm listing folder to backup, but I also need to backup every file that has a given extension like "*.jpeg"

The file name are changing everyday, that's why I need to use a wildcard but it's not accepted in a file list.

Is there a workaround to make this work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution I found is :   `tar -czvf backup.tar.gz $(cat filelist)`

Comment: This is a nice idea, but you could end up with an insanely long arguments list.  Which would then cause problems with the shell.

Comment: What kind of problems/limitations ?

Comment: ARG_MAX -- see here : http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2803

Comment: This was perfect for me.  I tried putting wild cards in the -T file list, and found out that didn't work.  This solution worked like a charm!    I don't know what the file limit would be though, so I'm checking out the link above this comment.  (Edit:  The above link is no longer available (snippets....))

Answer (score 2):

Have you try using --wildcards ?

```
 tar -xf foo.tar -v --wildcards '*.c'
```

http://www.gnu.org/s/tar/manual/html_section/wildcards.html

Comment: I tried and looks like --wildcards only works for extraction, doesn't work with -cf

Answer (score 1):

Create a filelist.template that contains the static folders to always backup and then copy it to filelist each time and add in all the `.jpeg` files. Something like:

```
cp filelist.template filelist
ls *.jpeg >> filelist
tar -czvf backup.tar.gz -T filelist
```

you could also use a `find` command instead of `ls` if you need `*.jpeg` from a variety of locations.